# Given edges, how can find routes that consists of two edges in a vectorised way?

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension, combinations

I have an array of towns and their neighbours. I want to get a set all the pairs of towns that have at least one route that consists of **exactly** two different edges. Is there a vectorized way to do this? If no, why? For example: edges `[3,0], [0,4], [5,0]` has an incident node 0 so it's quaranteed that `[3,4], [4,5], [3,5]` are pairs of towns that can be connected in routes likes so: `3-0-4`, `4-0-5` and `3-0-5`. They consist of two edges.

Example of input: `np.array([[3,0], [0,4], [5,0], [2,1], [1,4], [2,3], [5,2]])`

Expected output: `array([4,3], [4,5], [3,5], [4,2], [1,3], [1,5], [3,5], [0,2], [0,1], [0,2])`
(No worries if order is different, any of edge directions are reversed or there are duplicates)

There is what I have done so far:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def get_incidences(roads):
    roads = np.vstack([roads, roads[:,::-1]])
    roads_sorted = roads[np.argsort(roads[:,0])]
    marker_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(roads_sorted[:,0]))+1
    source = roads_sorted[np.r_[marker_idx-1,-1],0]
    target = np.split(roads_sorted[:,1], marker_idx)
    return source, target

def get_combinations_chain(target):
    #I know this could be improved with `np.fromiter`
    return np.array(list(chain(*[combinations(n,2) for n in target])))

def get_combinations_triu(target):
    def combs(t):
        x, y = np.triu_indices(len(t),1)
        return np.transpose(np.array([t[x], t[y]]))
    return np.concatenate([combs(n) for n in target])

roads = np.array([[3,0], [0,4], [5,0], [2,1], [1,4], [2,3], [5,2]])

>>> get_incidences(roads)
(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
 [array([4, 3, 5]),
  array([4, 2]),
  array([1, 3, 5]),
  array([0, 2]),
  array([0, 1]),
  array([0, 2])])
>>> get_combinations_chain(get_incidences(roads)[1])
array([[4, 3], [4, 5], [3, 5], [4, 2], [1, 3], [1, 5], [3, 5], [0, 2], [0, 1], [0, 2]])
>>> get_combinations_triu(get_incidences(roads)[1])
array([[4, 3], [4, 5], [3, 5], [4, 2], [1, 3], [1, 5], [3, 5], [0, 2], [0, 1], [0, 2]])
```

The last two ones give an expected output but they require a list comprehension. Is it possible to vectorize this calculation:

```
np.concatenate([combs(n) for n in target])
```

**Update** I ended with a possible way of vectorization but I needed to reorganize an input data (output of `get_incidences`):

```
INPUT:
target: [array([4, 3, 5]), array([4, 2]), array([1, 3, 5]), array([0, 2]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 2])]
stream: [4 3 5 4 2 1 3 5 0 2 0 1 0 2]
lengths: [3 2 3 2 2 2]
OUTPUT:
array([[3, 4], [4, 5], [3, 5], [2, 4], [1, 3], [1, 5], [3, 5], [0, 2], [0, 1], [0, 2]])
```

It also appears to be faster than straightforward concatenation of all the combinations:

```
def get_incidences(roads):
    roads = np.vstack([roads, roads[:,::-1]])
    roads_sorted = roads[np.argsort(roads[:,0])]
    marker_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(roads_sorted[:,0]))+1
    lengths = np.diff(marker_idx, prepend=0, append=len(roads_sorted))
    stream = roads_sorted[:,1]
    target = np.split(stream, marker_idx)
    return target, stream, lengths

def get_combinations_vectorized(data):
    target, stream, lengths = data
    idx1 = np.concatenate(np.repeat(target, lengths))
    idx2 = np.repeat(stream, np.repeat(lengths, lengths))
    return np.array([idx1, idx2]).T[idx1 < idx2]

def get_combinations_triu(data):
    target, stream, lengths = data
    def combs(t):
        x, y = np.triu_indices(len(t),1)
        return np.transpose(np.array([t[x], t[y]]))
    return np.concatenate([combs(n) for n in target])

def get_combinations_chain(data):
    target, stream, lengths = data
    return np.array(list(chain(*[combinations(n,2) for n in target])))

def get_combinations_scott(data):
    target, stream, lengths = data
    return np.array([x for i in target for x in combinations(i,2)])

def get_combinations_index(data):
    target, stream, lengths = data
    index = np.fromiter(chain.from_iterable(chain.from_iterable(combinations(n,2) for n in target)), 
                        dtype=int, count=np.sum(lengths*(lengths-1)))
    return index.reshape(-1,2)

roads = np.array([[64, 53], [94, 90], [24, 60], [45, 44], [83, 17], [10, 88], [14, 6], [56, 93], [98, 93], [86, 77], [12, 85], [58, 2], [19, 80], [48, 26], [11, 51], [16, 83], [45, 96], [35, 54], [47, 23], [81, 57], [52, 34], [88, 11], [18, 4], [35, 90], [41, 45], [2, 7], [58, 68], [58, 11], [46, 38], [32, 93], [44, 41], [26, 39], [20, 58], [44, 4], [8, 96], [74, 71], [34, 35], [91, 72], [28, 58], [53, 73], [66, 5], [84, 97], [24, 29], [43, 63], [96, 63], [20, 57], [1, 74], [4, 89], [10, 89], [98, 22]])
data = get_incidences(roads)

%timeit get_combinations_vectorized(data)
%timeit get_combinations_chain(data)
%timeit get_combinations_triu(data)
%timeit get_combinations_scott(data)
%timeit get_combinations_index(data)

92 µs ± 18.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
123 µs ± 3.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
1.8 ms ± 9.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
126 µs ± 2.45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
140 µs ± 4.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

However, it depends a lot on data. Timings for `roads = np.array(list(combinations(range(100),2)))`

```
44.2 ms ± 4.36 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
277 ms ± 8.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
21.2 ms ± 1.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
369 ms ± 17.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
43.2 ms ± 911 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: What do you mean, "at least one route that consisits [sic] of two different routes"?  This seems to be a contradiction.

Comment: Please explain your input and output more clearly.  "an array of towns and their neighbors" appears to be, instead, an edge list.  Your output appears to be pairs of nodes for some other reason -- but there are no "routes" that I can see.

Comment: If you have a graph problem, why are you using NumPy instead of a graph package?

Comment: @Prune That's a typo in "at least one route that consisits [sic] of two different routes", I fixed it. "an array of towns and their neighbors", - yeah, that's a different wording for edge list. Routes shouldn't be visible, it's only important to make sure that they all contains two edges

Comment: It's still not accurate.  The graph is a pair of connected cycles -- there is a path of at least two edges between *any* pair of nodes.

Comment: @Prune You might like to check my update. `4-1` is a contra-example. It clearly has a route that consists a single edge `4-1` but no routes that has two edges could be found.

Comment: @Prune I'm doing a lot of exercises these days to learn implementing some algorithms from scratch and efficiently on my own. Graph packages are good too but they are different category of learning, more about applying existing methods in graph theory.

Comment: @Prune I was asking about `at least one route that consists of two different edges` not `at least two edges between pair of nodes`. Is there anything with my wording?

Comment: 4-1 has this longer route: 4-0-3-2-1

Comment: @Prune Should I tell that a route must consist of **exactly** two different edges?

Comment: Yes -- and I'm glad you cleared that up at last.  Your previous comment says "at least two edges", which is a distinctly different problem.  If you merely want *some* solution, @Scott has given you a lovely one using the most popular graph package, as I suggested earlier.  If you want help with *your* code, please document it well, rather than hoping someone will reverse-engineer your intended algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the networkx library:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import combinations

a = np.array([[3,0], [0,4], [5,0], [2,1], [1,4], [2,3], [5,2]])

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edges_from(a)

#Creates this newtork
nx.draw_networkx(G)
```

[image]

```
# Create pairs of all nodes in network
c = combinations(G.nodes, 2)

# Find all routes between each pair in the network
routes = [list(nx.all_simple_paths(G, i, j, cutoff=2))[0] for i, j in c]

# Select only routes with three nodes/two edges the show first and last node
paths_2_edges = [(i[0], i[-1]) for i in routes if len(i) == 3]
print(paths_2_edges)
```

Output:

```
[(3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 1), (0, 2), (0, 1), (4, 5), (4, 2), (5, 1)]
```

---

#### Per comments

Vectorize this statement: `np.concatenate([combs(n) for n in target])`:

For `t = get_incidences(roads)[1]`

```
s2 = get_combinations_triu(t)
```

Output s2:

```
array([[4, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [3, 5],
       [4, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 5],
       [3, 5],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2]])

%timeit get_combinations_triu(t)
```

> 96.9 µs ± 3.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

---

Then

```
s1 = np.array([x for i in t for x in combinations(i,2)])
```

Output s1:

```
array([[4, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [3, 5],
       [4, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 5],
       [3, 5],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2]])
```

And, (s1 == s2).all()

```
True
```

Timeit:

```
%timeit np.array([x for i in t for x in list(combinations(i,2))])
```

> 14.7 µs ± 577 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Comment: Thanks for a reference to `nx.all_simple_paths` method. This is useful because I'm scanning `networkx` methods too but the main question is how can I vectorise this row of my script: `np.concatenate([combs(n) for n in target])`. If there are no opinions on this question, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @mathfux  Looks like using list comprehension maybe faster.  You'll have to test it on a much large dataset.

Comment: You're right `np.concatenate` can't outperform comprehensions here. But it helped me to vectorize a solution.

Comment: `nx.all_simple_paths` appears to be quite slow (at least 25x slower than your approach with list comprehension)
. Searching all paths for every possible pair of nodes seems like an overhead. Do you know faster methods of `networkx` in this scenario?

Comment: Hrm.. Maybe you could use parallel processing to search each start node.