# Build adjacency matrix from a list of nodes by avoiding for loops

Tags: python, list, numpy, python-itertools, adjacency-matrix

**What l need to solve ?**

Build a binary matrix from a list of indices.
Here is how l proceed but l would like to get an efficient way to do that avoiding loops

**Input :**

```
list_indices =[
[0,3,4],
[2,1,0],
[3,5]
]
```

**Expected output :**

```
results=[
[0,1,1,1,1,0],
[1,0,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,1,1],
[1,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0,0],
]
```

results correspond to a binary adjacency (symmetric) matrix constructed from a list of indices. 1 in results correspond to a pair of indices belonging to the same row of list_indices.

**The pairs from list_indices are :**

```
row 1 : (0,3), (3,0), (0,4),(4,0), (3,4), (4,3)
row 2 : (0,1), (1,0), (2,0), (0,2),(1,2), (2,1)
row 3 : (3,5), (5,3)


number of column and number of rows in results = np.max(list_indices)+1=6
```

**What l have tried ?**

```
results=np.zeros((np.max(list_indices)+1,np.max(list_indices)+1))

for pair in itertools.combinations(list_indices, r=2) :
                      
         results[pair[0],pair[1]]=results[pair[1],pair[0]]=1.0
```

What is the efficient way to build that  ? **(avoiding loops)**

`itertools.combinations` returns a list of pairs which are then used to fill the matrix results. Since the matrix is symmetric, itertools.combinations provides a list of pairs corresponding to the upper diagonal matrix.  diagonal is set to zero

Comment: What makes you think that this for loop is not efficient? Whatever is done will have to iterate over all pairs of indices.

Comment: l am looking for a pytonic/vectorized way to write that.  I think it is not efficient in the case of 200,000 pairs and matrix of 700,000 elements to fill

Comment: What a [déjà-vu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64359751/). It appears to be a problem of union of all simple paths (hint: `networkx.all_simple_paths(G, i, j, cutoff=2)` for every pair `(i, j)` of vertices of `networkx.Graph(G)`. This problem arose when I attempted to solve problem 3 in Graphs Arcade of Codesignal so I underwent a long process of researches. I found some solution finally, going to post it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is related strongly with my investigations [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64359751/) before 10 days, so I'll post a summary of the most important discoveries here.

- Storing communities as lists of unbalanced lengths forces to use iterations or concatenations which is not efficient. Instead you could use a single array and counts like so:

  ```
      flow = [0,3,4,2,1,0,3,5]
      counts = [3,3,2]
  ```
- A faster way for single combinations is a `np.triu_indices` method instead of `itertools.combinations`:

  ```
  def combs(t):
       x, y = np.triu_indices(len(t), 1)
       return np.transpose([t[x], t[y]])
  ```

  It is pointed out in my solution that you are looking how to avoid both concatenation and list comprehension in:

  ```
  np.concatenate([combs(n) for n in list_indices])
  ```

  or, alternatively (`from itertools import*`):

  ```
  np.array(list(chain(*[combinations(n,2) for n in list_indices])))
  ```
- I found a couple ways to vectorise it depending on your input:

  ```
  def repeat_blocks(a, sizes, repeats):
      #Thanks @Divakar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51156138/3044825
      r1 = np.repeat(np.arange(len(sizes)), repeats)
      N = (sizes*repeats).sum() # or np.dot(sizes, repeats)
      id_ar = np.ones(N, dtype=int)
      id_ar[0] = 0
      insert_index = sizes[r1[:-1]].cumsum()
      insert_val = (1-sizes)[r1[:-1]]
      insert_val[r1[1:] != r1[:-1]] = 1
      id_ar[insert_index] = insert_val
      out = a[id_ar.cumsum()] 
      return out

  def concat_combs1(flow, counts):
      #way 1 based on repetition of blocks of consecutive items
      col1 = repeat_blocks(flow, counts, counts)
      col2 = np.repeat(flow, np.repeat(counts, counts))
      return np.transpose([col1, col2])[col1 < col2]

  def concat_combs2(targets, counts):
      #way 2 based on repetition of blocks dissociated from each other
      counts = list(map(len, targets))
      col1 = np.concatenate(np.repeat(targets, counts, axis=0))
      col2 = np.repeat(np.concatenate(targets), np.repeat(counts, counts))
      return np.transpose([col1, col2])[col1 < col2]
  ```

  Test:

  ```
  list_indices = [np.array([0,3,4]), np.array([2,1,0]), np.array([3,5])]
  flow = np.array([0,3,4,2,1,0,3,5])
  counts = np.array([3, 3, 2])
  # Usage:
  np.concatenate([combs(n) for n in list_indices])
  concat_combs1(flow, counts)
  concat_combs2(list_indices)
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  array([[0, 3],
         [0, 4],
         [3, 4],
         [1, 2],
         [0, 2],
         [0, 1],
         [3, 5]])
  ```

#### Conclusion

Four methods has been `perfplot`ed on `igraph.Graph.Barabasi(n = x, m = 3)` including `itertools.combinations` and `np.triu_indices`. Each vertex of this graph has 3 neighbours in average. In conclusion, [connection of repeated consecutive blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51156138/3044825) works the best. Concatenation of numpy arrays is slower than chaining combinations for this time because very large number of small lists is being concatenated.

[image]

#### Final solution

In order to construct a matrix of incidence in a fastest way, you need to apply a small variation of `concat_combs1` method:

```
flow = np.array([0,3,4,2,1,0,3,5])
counts = np.array([3,3,2])
results = np.zeros((np.max(flow)+1, np.max(flow)+1), dtype=int)
col1 = repeat_blocks(flow, counts, counts)
col2 = np.repeat(flow, np.repeat(counts, counts))
results[col1, col2] = 1
np.fill_diagonal(results, 0)
```

#### Output

```
[[0 1 1 1 1 0]
 [1 0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 1 1]
 [1 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0]]
```