# numpy method instead of for

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe like below (yellow highlight represent sample co-occurrence of columns):

[image: yellow highlight represent sample co-occurrence of columns]

I need to form a matrix in which elements are the sum of co-occurrence of columns through the whole dataframe

for example, `element(i,j)` in my desired matrix represents how many times column `i` and `j` are both `1`  (highlighted in above figure).

I have written this code but it is not a good way ...can anyone help me write with numpy (or other efficient method)

```
######## co-occurrence of tags
co_occur=np.zeros(25*25)
co_occur=co_occur.reshape(25,25)
def co_occurance(i,j):
    k=0
    for index,row in train_data.iterrows():
        if row.iloc[i+2]==1:
            if row.iloc[j+2]==1:
                k+=1
    return k

for i in range(1,25):
    for j in range(i+1,25):
        co_occur[i,j]=co_occurance(i,j)
```

25 is number of columns.

Comment: I assume finding `groups` of indices of nonzero values for each row is quite an easy. As it's done, it appears to be quite a complicated problem that [has been discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64541363/3044825) a long time before. If you are good with loops, use `numba` to optimised it. Otherwise you've got a problem of type `np.concatenate([combinations(g, 2) for g in groups])` which is solvable resulting in a quite complicated solution. Have you got any additional info about maximum number of nonzero values per row?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't add data or code as images. Instead use plain text or better yet, provide a piece of code that constructs the dataframe. This will make it much more likely that someone is quickly able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you can do it in pure numpy, i don't know how. but here's my solution anyway

```
from itertools import permutations

co_occur=np.zeros((25,25))

# get all rows where sum>1
rows=np.where(np.sum(train_data,1)>1)
for row in rows[0]:
    # get all indices of columns with value=1
    idx=np.where(train_data[row]==1)
    # and add +1 in every combination of indices
    for comb in permutations(idx[0],r=2):
        co_occur[comb]+=1
```